# How to disassemble these parts?

Tags: disassembly

I have these parts put together really tightly and have no idea how to separate them. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Sorry for the black color, I do not have them in any of the brighter colors, so I put the separated ones on the photo for clarity.

Comment: I would probably, unfortunately, use a knife here. Especially if these parts are old.

Comment: I thought that it might be the only solution. I cannot believe LEGO decided to use this assembly (in set 8466).

Comment: I think Lego has already considered this problem. The plate has already a rounded corner so that you can separate them even with your fingernails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is unfortunate situation. What makes your matter worse is that these two parts come from quite old set (OP mentioned 8466). Aged parts tend to have stronger clutch power than the newer parts. Even if these two parts were new they would be pretty hard to take apart. In this situation I think the only solution is taking sharp knife (like x-acto or utility knife) and gently go around the edge where two parts get together to try and make them go apart slightly. I would recommend using the edge of the blade, rather than the sharp point first. Don't try to disassemble them with one go, but rather do it gently around with your knife until you get some progress.

Alternatively, if parts cannot be disassembled, you have two more options:

1. Get in touch with LEGO Support and complain about it. It is highly likely they will just ship you new parts, despite set being so old.
2. You can buy them yourself. Parts are:

32017 - [Technic, Liftarm 1 x 5 Thin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32017)

32124 - [Technic, Plate 1 x 5 with Smooth Ends, 4 Studs and Center Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32124)

Comment: I managed to separate them after rinsing them in soapy water for a few minutes and then gently pushing the knife along the longer side of the parts. They came apart surprisingly easily.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what pieces you have in your collection to build the perfect most creative piece separator, so my answer will be based on, *"What common items do many people have on hand in a house?"*

- Try a dull butter knife.

***EDIT:***

Or we can just ignore what I said, and make something simple with pieces many of us should have.

- Find any sized beam 5 pin holes or above.
- Insert some pegs in the holes.
- Place stuck pieces on top.
- Apply downward pressure mainly holding from the black piece (Part 32017) to create a starting point of separation.
- Once a gap has started it can be easily "unzipped" apart by running a
  finger nail/plastic knife down the gap.

[image]

Comment: I'd go with sharp knife instead. As if there was a gap to insert blunt knife, you could get these pieces apart with fingers.

Comment: In my house, with me, I'd go full brain surgan with a x-acto knife, but I don't know the skill level/age of the OP.  Start with dull, work your way up.  Safety first.

Comment: Posting after your edit. I've examined your proposed solution, and I'm afraid to say that it simply won't work. Your suggestion results in pushing one part with all the pins without having anything attached to another one. So basically you are doing nothing here.

Comment: Alex, in your astute examination of my work you've misunderstood where the pressure would be applied.  I'll update my answer with an animation for the kiddies.  Now, Alec, look at the moving picture, how/where would one hold the piece to accomplish the feat of creating a starting point gap?  A) The Red piece.  B) The Blue piece  C) Hold and press down from the Black piece.  D) None of the above. See how it simply works, Alec?

Comment: Maybe the use of the floating cross peg was confusing, so I took it out, but to claim as you've done in your answer, that a sharp object is the "only" solution is simply lazy, irresponsible to young children, and negates the multiple creative solutions playing with LEGOs is all about.

Comment: Is my solution the "only" solution? No. Creating a gap could be done with one peg and one beam, but actually siting down and playing with the pieces vs, running off to LEGO support to make a complaint... Seriously?  We need to stop complaining. Sit down. Do the work. Come up with quality solutions.  Edit. Repeat.

Comment: I'm sure your solution works nicely on GIF. However, unfortunately, I hardly see how this is an improvement over previous picture. Your proposed solution is based on the fact you can somehow grab liftarm,  and later push it apart. The I see here - there's nowhere to grab that liftarm to push it away. If there WAS a sufficient gap between the parts you basically wouldn't have this question raised by OP. To make things worse you have to account for these parts being quite old. And old parts have greater clutch power for some reason.

Comment: You're right. There is no improvement. it's the same setup you wrote in your words, "I'm afraid to say that it simply won't work. Your suggestion results in pushing one part with all the pins without having anything attached to another one. So basically you are doing nothing here." Okay, smart Aleck.  Let's word dance and explain ourselves out of being wrong.  The answer is "C".

Comment: Do you have these pieces or their equivalent? Did you actually sit yourself down and play out the impossibility of grabbing the lift arm?  If you did, you would've learned a solution that was both better then the GIF, and way kid friendlier then using a knife. Instead of short circuiting playful learning with suggestions that serve your way as the "only" way, post up an alternate solution. We'll patiently wait...

Comment: Since we're going to LEGO for complaints to stifle learning, let's ask them if they condone using a sharp x-acto knife as the "only" way to separate pieces... I'm sure they're on board with that/s.